# People Modern Webpart not refreshing profile pictures

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, modern, cmdlets

We have updated hundreds of our users Profile pictures with the cmdlet

```
Set-UserPhoto
```

These images propagate pictures across Delve, Office, Exchange and SharePoint but it will not force update the 'People' Modern webpart. I have to manually remove and re-add each user for the thumbnail image to refresh with their picture. Is there a command I can use to force the cache to reset on these webparts since they exist in every site!?

[image]

Comment: How long have you waited?

Comment: We have waited 3 days. The manual update works for most but not all.

Comment: If you're waiting >24 hours, open a support ticket with Microsoft.